# How to capture non commented lines of code from a text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file that goes something like this:

```
#<[_MOUNTING] Recessed
#<[_FAMILY] RT8
#<[_PRODUCTID] cecf8545-0ff3-4d4a-bafd-dbb156bab282
#<[_BALLAST_TYPE] ELECTRONIC
#<[_FIXTURE_TYPE] 2X4 Volumetric
#<[_TERCAT] Recessed, Linear
#<[_TER] 72
# 54.8 watt luminaire, lamp*ballast factor = 1

void brightdata 2RT8S_2_32_LP735_dist
23 flatcorr C:/rm/ies/2RT8S_2_32_LP735.dat source.cal src_phi4 src_theta -i 1 -t 3.2 0.9 2.9 -i 0 -t 2.44 0.0 0.0 -i 0 -t -0.0 1.83 0.0
0
1            1.54935


# c:\daysim\bin\xform -n a0.1 -t 3.2 0.9 2.9 -i 0 -t 2.44 0.0 0.0 -i 1 -t -0.0 1.83 0.0
# c:\daysim\bin\ies2rad -dm -m 0.95 -t white -o C:/rm/ies/2RT8S_2_32_LP735
# Dimensions in meters
#<[_PRODUCTID] cecf8545-0ff3-4d4a-bafd-dbb156bab282
#<[_BALLAST_TYPE] ELECTRONIC
#<[_FIXTURE_TYPE] 2X4 Volumetric
#<[_TERCAT] Recessed, Linear
#<[_TER] 72
# 54.8 watt luminaire, lamp*ballast factor = 1

void brightdata 2RT8S_2_32_LP735_dist
23 flatcorr C:/rm/ies/2RT8S_2_32_LP735.dat source.cal src_phi4 src_theta -i 1 -t 3.2 0.9 2.9 -i 0 -t 2.44 0.0 0.0 -i 1 -t -0.0 1.83 0.0
0
1            1.54935

2RT8S_2_32_LP735_dist light 2RT8S_2_32_LP735_light
0
0
3                  1                  1                  1

# c:\daysim\bin\xform -n a0.2 -t 3.2 0.9 2.9 -i 0 -t 2.44 0.0 0.0 -i 2 -t -0.0 1.83 0.0
# c:\daysim\bin\ies2rad -dm -m 0.95 -t white -o C:/rm/ies/2RT8S_2_32_LP735
# Dimensions in meters
#<IESNA:LM-63-2002
#<[TEST] LTL18481
#<[TESTDATE] 1/28/2010
```

I want to capture the non commented lines of code and write them into separate files. What would be, for the lack of a better word, the most 'pythonic' way to do this? I have already made it work, however I don't think that my way is very elegant. My code is below.

```
from __future__ import print_function
lumdict={}
counter = 1
b =False

with open(radFile) as rad:
    a=[] #Create a temp list to capture noncommented data.
    for lines in rad:

        if not lines.startswith("#"):
            a.append(lines) #Add non commented data to templist
        else:
            if len(a)>0: 
                lumdict[counter]=a #Capture non commented data into a dictionary.
                b=a[:] #This is the list meant to be used for the last bit of non commented data.
                a=[]
                counter +=1
    else:
        lumdict[counter]=b


for zones,radvalues in lumdict.items(): #Write the dictionary to individual files.
    with open(r'd:\zones\{}.rad'.format(zones),'w') as zonefile:
        for lines in radvalues:
            print(lines,file=zonefile,end="")
```

Comment: Maybe you can clarify a bit. From your solution, it looks like you want to capture each block of uncommented lines between comments into its own file, rather than each uncommented line to a separate file. Is this correct?

Comment: The purpose of `b` is not fully clear. Initially it's a boolean value (False) but then it becomes a list. Also, what's the precise purpose of the `for-else` branch?

Comment: @EricAppelt Yes, exactly as you stated.

Comment: Is there a bug in your code when your file ends on a non-comment. I feel like the last block of none commented code would be left out of the dictionary.

Comment: @dlask Well, my code is pretty hacky here. So, b is meant to capture the last block of uncommented code. So, the else in the for-else captures that last block and keys it in to the dictionary.  Then I iterate through the dict and write each of thes keys to a separate file.

Comment: @DTing Yup :) there is a tiny bug. That is why I am implementing a for -else so that I can catch the last block.  Good 'catch' by you though ! It was only apparent to me once I ran the code that there was this bug.

Comment: See my answer. Also prevents you from having to store the entire file contents in a dictionary. For your current code, you can get rid of `b` and check if there is anything in `a` after the `for loop` completes. If there is then set a lumdict[counter] = a. `if a: lumdict[counter] = a`. The current code wont do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to file while iterating rather than create a dictionary with something along the lines of:

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open(radFile) as rad:
    counter = 0
    zonefile = open(r'd:\zones\{}.rad'.format(counter),'w')
    for line in rad:
        if not line.startswith("#"):
            if zonefile.closed:
                counter += 1
                zonefile = open(r'd:\zones\{}.rad'.format(counter),'w')
            print(line, file=zonefile)
        else:
            zonefile.close()
    zonefile.close()
```

Comment: Your solution is a lot better than what I came up with. A couple of things however, I think the 'line' fourth line from the end should be 'lines'. And your code creates an empty file first up. But these are things that I can handle. So, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know you are asking for a python implement. But as a alternative, you can just choose to use shell command to do this:

```
grep -v '^#' foo.txt > bar.txt
```

Comment: Well, I am implementing this code inside Rhino-Grasshopper, which incidentally, only runs on windows. Thanks for letting me know this though.